# Unable to connect to SFTP neither using Filezilla nor PuTTY (client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

Everything was working this morning but maybe I broke something with my SFTP user. On FileZilla, I was unable to download a file from my Virtualbox VM so I decided to restart my FileZilla client and then I was unable to reconnect.

Here are my configurations for **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /var/www
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

FileZilla output:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1...
Status: Using username "sftpuser". 
Command:    Pass: **********
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Command:    open "sftpuser@127.0.0.1" 22
Status: Using username "sftpuser". 
Command:    Pass: **********
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

PuTTY output:

```
$ sftp sftpuser@127.0.0.1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

SSH output:

```
$ ls -lua
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 june  21 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root      4096 june  21 00:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 27 www-data www-data 12288 june  21 00:00 foo
drwxrwxr-x 30 www-data www-data  4096 june  21 00:00 bar
drwxrwxr-x 27 www-data www-data  4096 june  21 00:00 baz
```

SSH log using **journalctl -u ssh | tail -n 12**:

```
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14508]: Accepted password for sftpuser from 10.0.2.2 port 54811 ssh2
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14508]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpuser(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14508]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14653]: Accepted password for sftpuser from 10.0.2.2 port 54816 ssh2
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14653]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpuser(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[14653]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15041]: Accepted password for sftpuser from 10.0.2.2 port 54817 ssh2
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15041]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpuser(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15041]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15119]: Accepted password for sftpuser from 127.0.0.1 port 54046 ssh2
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15119]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpuser(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
june 21 00:00:00 developer sshd[15119]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser
```

I think it's a permission issue but I don't know where I would have to look.
Do you have any ideas ?

Edit: I didn't mention it because it was obvious for me but connecting with any other user with SSH is working on PuTTY

Thank you !

Comment: Your `sshd_config` isn't self-consistent. You've got a `Subsystem sftp` to the external OpenSSH utility that handles `sftp`, but a ForceCommand of `internal-sftp` that won't work because the point is that `internal-sftp` isn't a command. Which do you really want to use?

Comment: Does connecting to the server `127.0.0.1` with `ssh` work for this user account? Did it work previously? Does connecting to the server `127.0.0.1` with `ssh` work for other user accounts, or is there some other change too?

Comment: @roaima I understand that it isn't self-consistent and I don't know which one I should use but I guess I would use openssh. However, it was working with this same config earlier on 
The connection with SSH works for all my users on 127.0.0.1 excepted for sftp (but it's because of the config which only allows this user to connect using the sftp protocol)

Comment: Do you happend to have a MOTD when you connect via SSH to your server ? It might be only that.

Comment: @yield as I told you yesterday on your previous comment ; I do have some motd but it was working well with it. I tried to remove all of them but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to retry to create a SFTP on another VM because I was doing a new dev environment and had the same issue. I fixed the issue giving the good permissions in the home directory of the sftp user and creating a mounted folder to access to my
/var/www

I followed this tutorial: https://gaelbillon.com/create-a-sftp-user-restricted-to-a-var-www-directory-on-ubuntu-debian/
If you ever face this issue, I recommend you to just retry from the beginning !